# Does priority override the order of execution specified in testng.xml

Tags: testng

So i have suppose two test classes A and B with a test method each.

If i Specify a lower priority to the test method in A and higher priority to method in B. And in the testng.xml B is specified first and then A and preserveOrder is set to true, in such a scenario the test of A is not executed first even though it has lower priority. (althought Lower priorities should be scheduled first). Is there anyway to execute test A and then B?

Not sure if depends on will work in this case. But both the methods have same name.

Answer (score 1):

Set **preserve-order="false"** at test level. i.e.

for structure like:

```
Class1- method1 - priority = 2
        method2 - priority = 4
Class2- method1 - priority = 1
        method2 - priority = 3
```

and test xml as:

```
<test name="priority test" preserve-order="false">
    <classes>
        <class name="stackoverflow.Class1" />
        <class name="stackoverflow.Class2"></class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

You will have op as:

```
method1(class 2)
method1(class 1)
method2(class 2)
method2(class 1)
```

and with **preserve-order="true"** or without this tag u'll have OP as

```
method1(class 1)
method2(class 1)
method1(class 2)
method2(class 2)
```

You can even group the tests.
Hope this might help you.

Comment: yeah but Preserver order has to be true. That is the first requirement. Anyways I have a found a different way to solve the issue. I am generating the testng.xml dynamically based on some logic.

Comment: But a qq did u see anything which can get this question a downvote ? Last 3 questions i asked and all got downvoted for some reason which was never specified.

Comment: Its a good practice here in SO if you provide ur ques with some sample code. You might have accompanied it with your limitations too. The way you framed your question might have seemed to the viewer with no reseacrh efforts provided. So s/he might have downvoted. Don't  worry, sometimes criticism also improves one. And it would be great that if you found a workaround, you answer your own ques, so that others can get help from it. Thanks. Happy to help!